# Trigger keyboard backspace event

Tags: javascript, jquery, real-time, keypress

i need to trigger an actual backspace to happen in real time via the code. I can not take the content and remove the last typed character and then populate it again.

Also creating an event and then triggering it using the jquery trigger does not work .

Any suggestions or any known piece of work?

Comment: If I may ask... Why are you able to trigger events but not able to manipulate the content itself?

Comment: Because replacing the `value` of an element causes the Undo/Redo history to be wiped. @bhumi-singhal may be attempting to avoid this.

Have you looked into [dispatchEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/EventTarget.dispatchEvent)?

Comment: @JulianH.Lam I read that dispatch events are not handeled by all the browsers and so i dint look into it further. I surely will now

Comment: @Nirazul - I am avoiding the amnipulation of the content as when i will reinsert the content then I will have to again manipulate the cursor position. Also there no specific cross browser compatibility code available to get the cursor postion and then put it back again at that same place. If you have that code please post here.

Comment: I still doubt, that there is a need for this behaviour. If you could give us an example of your use case, maybe someone comes up with an alternative.

Comment: @Nirazul - I have an editor. What I require is that each of the multiple lines entered by the user should not exceed 200px. As in, when the user is typing, after reaching 200+-10px, he/she should not be able to type.This is to happen for EACH line and not the content as a whole.Also, the user can always go back to a previous line using the arrow keys and start typing from the middle of the sentence.

Comment: For me this sounds like the functionality of a textarea. Set it to 200px and it breaks there. I'm still not sure why you want to force this behaviour since you always can go back and start typing in the middle of a sentence. What's the point then?

Comment: @Nirazul- all i need is to restrict the user from typping. Thats it.